# How to write the new RCT AppDelegate interface with User Notifications in ios on react-native

Tags: ios, react-native, appdelegate

I've recently upgraded my react-native SDK version to 0.73,
But according to the [Upgrade Helper here](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.70.8&to=0.73.2#RnDiffApp-ios-RnDiffApp-AppDelegate.h) the `AppDelegate` interface definition changed from

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, RCTBridgeDelegate>
```

to

```
@interface AppDelegate : RCTAppDelegate
```

But as my project uses "UserNotifications" which should be used to extend/implement the AppDelegate interface, I couldn't figure out how to extend this new interface.

Answer (score 0):

Alrighty, found it here: https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/issues/2344

To extend the AppDelegate interface with the latest react-native, I should use the obvious

```
#import <RCTAppDelegate.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <UserNotifications/UNUserNotificationCenter.h>

@interface AppDelegate : RCTAppDelegate <UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate>

@end
```